# renovate: automerge despite failed CI

Tags: cicd, gitea, renovate

I am using renovate and have configured it against gitea to update my repositories. Recently I upgraded to version 36.71.0. Since then renovate automatically merges PRs, even though the change via CI has led to errors.

Is there any configuration change regarding renovate version v32 and v36, that changes the behavior of renovate when automerge is enabled and the CI throws errors, with the suggested change?

Here are some links:

- [rpm-builder](https://git.cryptic.systems/volker.raschek/rpm-builder-docker)
- [renovate.json](https://git.cryptic.systems/volker.raschek/rpm-builder-docker/src/branch/master/renovate.json)
- [PR and merge](https://git.cryptic.systems/volker.raschek/rpm-builder-docker/pulls/18)

Volker

Comment: Not familiar with Gitea but look's like your PR checks were successful.